# UITableView index repeats after the 14th letter

Tags: ios, uitableview

i'm trying to make a table of letters with index, when i click on the first 14 letters it shows me the right letter but after that it keeps repeating itself and show me  only the 14th letter. please help.. here is my code: (the letters are not English :))

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _arr=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"א",@"ב",@"ג",@"ד",@"ה",@"ו",@"ז",@"ח",@"ט",@"י",@"כ",@"ל",@"מ",@"נ",@"ס",@"ע",@"פ",@"צ",@"ק",@"ר",@"ש",@"ת",nil];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [_arr count];
}

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return self.arr;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString*)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    int position;
    switch (index) {
        case 0:
            position=0;
            break;
        case 1:
            position=1;
            break;
        case 2:
            position=2;
            break;
        case 3:
            position=3;
            break;
        case 4:
            position=4;
            break;
        case 5:
            position=5;
            break;
        case 6:
            position=6;
            break;
        case 7:
            position=7;
            break;
        case 8:
            position=8;
            break;
        case 9:
            position=9;
            break;
        case 10:
            position=10;
            break;
        case 11:
            position=11;
            break;
        case 12:
            position=12;
            break;
        case 13:
            position=13;
            break;
        case 14:
            position=14;
            break;
        case 15:
            position=15;
            break;
        case 16:
            position=16;
            break;
        case 17:
            position=17;
            break;
        case 18:
            position=18;
            break;
        case 19:
            position=19;
            break;
        case 20:
            position=20;
            break;
        case 21:
            position=21;
            break;
        case 22:
            position=22;
            break;


        default:
            position=1;
            break;
    }
    NSLog(@"scrolling to %d",position);
    [tableView reloadInputViews];
    [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
    [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:position inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];

     return index;
}


- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.arr objectAtIndex:section];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

       cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:32];
       cell.textLabel.text=[_arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Don't you using `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` delegate of `UITableView`, it will give you the `index` of tapped cell. You've pass that `index` into your `arr` to get the tapped object.

Answer (score 0):

Everything here looks right, except for your `tableView:sectionForSectionIndexTitle:atIndex`.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString*)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    // First of all, we can greatly simplify it by removing your case statement
    // and replacing it with this:
    int position = 1;

    if (index < 23) {  // Or even better, use [_arr count]
        position = index;
    }

    NSLog(@"scrolling to %d",position);

    // Then, the following three lines should be deleted, as the tableview
    // automatically scrolls for you when an index is tapped:

    // [tableView reloadInputViews];
    // [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
    // [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:position inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];

    // Also, you should be returning position, and not index
    return position;
}
```

When you are using indexes, the tableview automatically takes care of the scrolling, so you should not be doing it yourself.  Just remove all of the `[tableView ...]` methods in this routine, and it should work for you.

So now, the short version would be:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString*)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    if (index < [_arr count]) {
        return index;
    }

    // Default
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: If this worked, please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark next to my answer.  This way the people who take the time to help you get credit for their answers.  Also, clicking the up arrow on ALL good answers (including the one that you accept) will give them credit as well.  Welcome to SO and please try to help others out as well!